# Как добавить текст в поле при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте ХешКод.

Есть кнопка и есть поле, мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в поле добавилось слово: "Привет".

Код:

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
<input type = "submit" value = "Добавить текст" />

<br /><br />

<input type = "text" name = "text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
  <input type = "submit" name="button_name" value = "Добавить текст" />
  <?php
    $text = '';
    if(isset($_POST['button_name'])){
      $text = 'привет';
    }
  ?>
  <input type = "text" name = "text" value = "<?php print $text; ?>" />
</form>
```

Воть. Но лучше это сделать через JS. Работать будет в разы быстрее, перезагрузка исчезнет.

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
  <input type = "submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value='Привет'" value = "Добавить текст" />
  <input type = "text" name = "text" id="text" value = "" />
</form>
```

Comment: Работает, а если например поле на одной странице, а кнопка на другой? Так можно сделать?

Comment: В поле action указать адрес той страницы, на которой поле.
На нее же перенести PHPшный кусок:

    <?php
    $text = '';
    if(isset($_POST['button_name'])){
      $text = 'привет';
    }
  ?>
  <input type = "text" name = "text" value = "<?php print $text; ?>" />

Comment: А через js можно между страничками передавать инфу? Просто у меня вторая страничка подгружается в iframe, вот смотрите что мне надо научится делать, у меня есть чат: http://chat-profit.org.ua/index.php вот там мне нужно под сообщением сделать кнопку типо ответить в в поле Введите сообщение, должен добавить ник того кто написал это сообщение.

Логин: Angus123
Пароль: 159357

Для более понятного объяснение, это как Цитаты на форуме.

ссылка это **не реклама** это просто мой проект, для которого я хочу это сделать.

Comment: можно и нужно! Правда, если это чат, лучше юзать ajax, иначе, боюсь, ответ увидите только вы

    var iframePageDocument = document.getElementById(Id of frame).contentDocument;
    onclick="iframePageDocument.getElementById('text').value='Привет'"